# Shadcn error module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/components/ui/accordion' in 'Desktop/sadcn/src'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, jsx, custom-component

i am using shadcn with simple react app with typescript installed but i'm getting this error

module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/components/ui/accordion' in '/home/vinayak/Desktop/sadcn/src'

i have installed it using shadcn cli and kept typescript component option as no so i get jsx components only every time.

here is my tsconfig file ::

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/": ["./*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my project tree

```
- .gitignore
- README.md
- app
  - globals.css
- components
  - ui
    - accordion.jsx
- components.json
- lib
  - utils.js
- package-lock.json
- package.json
- public
  - favicon.ico
  - index.html
  - logo192.png
  - logo512.png
  - manifest.json
  - robots.txt
- src
  - App.css
  - App.js
  - App.test.js
  - index.css
  - index.js
  - logo.svg
  - reportWebVitals.js
  - setupTests.js
- tailwind.config.js
- tsconfig.json
```

How to fir it ??

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue. Put this on your terminal :

- `npm install shadcn-ui@latest`
- `npm install npx shadcn-ui@latest init`